# Java and Windows - error: illegal escape character

Tags: java, windows, file-io

I have done my .java file that changes registry data. But I am getting "illegal escape character" error on the line where `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` exists. Where is my mistake ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.*; 

class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("REG ADD 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main' /V 'Start Page' /D 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/' /F");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error ocured!");
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to escape the *backslashes* used in your path.

```
String windowsPath = "\\Users\\FunkyGuy\\My Documents\\Hello.txt";
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape `\` with another `\`, so replace `\` with `\\` in your input string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash characters in your registry path string:

```
"REG ADD `HKCU\\Software\\ ...
```

The backslash character has a special meaning in strings: it's used to introduce escape characters. if you want to use it literally in a string, then you'll need to escape *it*, by using a double-backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Back slashes in Java are special "escape" characters, they provide the ability to include things like tabs `\t` and/or new lines `\n` and lots of other fun stuff.

Needless to say, you to to "escape" them as well by adding an addition `\` character...

```
'HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main'
```

On a side note. I would use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or at the very least, the version of `Runtime#exec` that uses [array arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).

It will save a lot of hassle when it comes to dealing with spaces within command parameters, IMHO

Comment: Almost everyone calls "\" a backslash not a forward slash.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

Comment: When I hear people say _forward slash_ on the radio when talking about URLs I want to go bananas!!

Comment: Not if you want people to understand what you are saying ... which I'd have thought was a prerequisite for answering Questions on SO.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the problem is: Mae eich hofrenfad yn llawn llyswennod trydan.

Comment: @StephenC 30 years playing with computers and still can't get my head around back and forward slashes...they've just become windows and unix slashes :P

Comment: @StephenC Besides, if you can't dazzle 'em with brilliance, baffle 'em with B*** ***t

Comment: (Damn ... you rumbled me :-) :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you didn't escape the backslash in your string. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html for more information about proper escaping.

Answer (score 1):

you need replace escape `\` with `\\`

below code will work

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("REG ADD 'HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main' /V 'Start Page' /D 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/' /F");
```